# How to Display next and previous records on clicking on next button in Java

Tags: java, sql

Hello Friends I am trying to diplay the records in my Jave Gui Application I have made some code it works but when I click on next button it displays the last record. Is there any another way to view the records present in between please help.

```
 private void bt_nextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if(evt.getSource()==bt_previous){
    DBUtil util = new DBUtil();
           try {
                Connection con = util.getConnection();
               PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT [box_no],[weight],[note_state],[dm_state],[1],[2],[5],[10],[20],[50],[100],[500],[1000] FROM [CNV].[dbo].[soil_det] where rm_id=?");
                ResultSet rs;
                String rm = tf_rm_id.getText().trim();

                stmt.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(rm));

                rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String a = rs.getString("weight");
                    txtboxwgt.setText(a);
                    String b = rs.getString("note_state");
                    cbnotstat.setSelectedItem(b);
                    String c = rs.getString("dm_state");
                    cbdmnstat.setSelectedItem(c);
                    txtboxno.setText(rs.getString("box_no"));
                    txtRe1.setText(rs.getString("1"));
                    txtRs2.setText(rs.getString("2"));
                    txtRs5.setText(rs.getString("5"));
                    txtRs10.setText(rs.getString("10"));
                    txtRs20.setText(rs.getString("20"));
                    txtRs50.setText(rs.getString("50"));
                    txtRs100.setText(rs.getString("100"));
                    txtRs500.setText(rs.getString("500"));
                    txtRs1000.setText(rs.getString("1000"));
                }

           } catch (Exception e) {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
                 }
    }


}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate your database code from your GUI code.  You also need to break up your application into smaller, more easily coded steps.

Here are the things that your application needs to do when starting:

- Open a connection to the database.
- Select all of the keys of the table soil_det, and save the keys in a List.
- Select the first row, and display it.

When the next button is left clicked:

- Get the next key from the List.
- Display a message if you're past the end of the List.
- Otherwise, select the current row, and display it.

When the previous button is left clicked:

- Get the previous key from the List.
- Display a message if you're past the beginning of the List.
- Otherwise, select the current row and display it.

Here are the things that your application needs to do when ending:

- Close the connection to the database.

Answer (score 2):

In your `while` loop, your `JTextFields` values are being set & re-set and remains set at the last value in the loop. Making separate calls for each button click has an expensive overhead but if you wish to use this approach you need an appropriate `WHERE` clause in your `SQL` that only returns one record. Also consider using [connection pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool).

Alternatively, you could display all values in a `JTable`.

[How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Ya brother its a point but the problem is I have created a DATABASE in SQL that is why I have to retrieve the values from my database and display them.... :-(

Comment: Can you explain further? Do you need the data displayed in a particular way?

Comment: Ya actually I was trying out JTable but its little complicated for me I was thinking if once we click on the next button the data records should be displayed from 1 and when we click on the next button again then on every click it should increment the cursor from one row to next row.