# how to display previous and next records in java

Tags: java, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Display next and previous records on clicking on next button in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402734/how-to-display-next-and-previous-records-on-clicking-on-next-button-in-java)

I am trying to display records from my database to my gui application in JAVA. I tried to run the below code but then I am getting the exception that operation is not supported dont know whats wrong with it.

```
 private void bt_previousActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if(evt.getSource()==bt_previous){

            DBUtil util = new DBUtil();
               try {
                    Connection con = util.getConnection();
                   PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT [box_no],[weight],[note_state],[dm_state],[1],[2],[5],[10],[20],[50],[100],[500],[1000] FROM [CNV].[dbo].[soil_det] where rm_id=?");
                    ResultSet rs;
                    String rm = tf_rm_id.getText().trim();

                    stmt.setLong(1, Long.parseLong(rm));

                    rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                    rs.getArray(WIDTH);
                    char n = WIDTH;
                    int i;
                    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
                        String a = rs.getString("weight");
                        txtboxwgt.setText(a);
                        String b = rs.getString("note_state");
                        cbnotstat.setSelectedItem(b);
                        String c = rs.getString("dm_state");
                        cbdmnstat.setSelectedItem(c);
                        txtboxno.setText(rs.getString("box_no"));
                        txtRe1.setText(rs.getString("1"));
                        txtRs2.setText(rs.getString("2"));
                        txtRs5.setText(rs.getString("5"));
                        txtRs10.setText(rs.getString("10"));
                        txtRs20.setText(rs.getString("20"));
                        txtRs50.setText(rs.getString("50"));
                        txtRs100.setText(rs.getString("100"));
                        txtRs500.setText(rs.getString("500"));
                        txtRs1000.setText(rs.getString("1000"));
                    }

               } catch (Exception e) {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
                     }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `ResultSet.next` after the call to `executeQuery`:

```
while (rs.next()) {
...
```

[PreparedStatement.executeQuery example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/tjvpsxqu.htm)