# Next button should get next record

Tags: android

```
package com.ctis.abc_final;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DisplayActivity extends Activity {

    DBAdapter db;

    TextView t1;
    TextView t2;
    TextView t3;
    TextView t4;
    TextView t5;
    TextView t6;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);

        try {
            String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName()
                    + "/databases/Ctis487";
            File file = new File(destPath);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("Ctis487"),
                        new FileOutputStream(destPath));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        t4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        t5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        t6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);

        db = new DBAdapter(this);

    }

    public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
            throws IOException {
        // Copy 1K bytes at a time
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.Button01:
            // Get all contacts
            db.open();
            Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    DisplayContact(c);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            db.close();

            break;
        }

    }

    public void DisplayContact(Cursor c) {

        t1.setText("" + c.getString(3));
        t2.setText("" + c.getString(1));
        t3.setText("" + c.getString(2));
        t4.setText("" + c.getString(4));
        t5.setText("" + c.getString(5));
        t6.setText("" + c.getString(6));

    }
}
```

Above code only get the last value. What i want to do is when you click the next button, it should get the next record. How can i do that? i defined on click above code. But it only retrieves last record why?

**this only retrieve first record. UPDATE Please look at it.**

```
switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.Button01:
            int record_position =  -1;

            // Get all contacts
            db.open();
            Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
            if (record_position == -1){
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    record_position = c.getPosition();
                    DisplayContact(c);
                }
            }
            else if (c.moveToPosition(record_position)){     
                c.moveToNext();
                record_position = c.getPosition();
                DisplayContact(c);
            }
            else {
                if(c.moveToFirst()){
                    record_position = c.getPosition();
                    DisplayContact(c);
                }
            }
            db.close();
            break;
```

Comment: Your loop is iterating over the whole set every time you click.

Comment: Follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14403757/1306419) answer

Comment: can you show how can i do that please

Comment: Move the record_placeholder out of the case switch. Currently you are setting it to -1 every time so it never increments.

Answer (score 0):

Only last values are displayed because, your while loop keeps calling the `DisplayContacts` function again and again. The loop exits only after setting those TextViews with values that were set by the final(last) to  `DisplayContacts` function. That is why you are seeing only the values set on the last call. The person in [How to Display next and previous records on clicking on next button in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402734/how-to-display-next-and-previous-records-on-clicking-on-next-button-in-java) question was doing the same thing wrong. It might be help you if you read through those answers.

One of the simple way to get get the next value on clicking of next button would be follows:

-> Declare the database functionality outside the `onClick` function( maybe in onCreate or using AsyncTask). This would prevent you from going to database again and again, as making a call can be expensive.

-> Then get the result in form of `ArrayList` and iterate over it on clicking of next button.

Hope this gives you some idea of how you might approach it.

Comment: I am pretty sure this has been asked before. You can try seeing the answer on almost similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452310/getting-the-next-record-into-view-from-database). Hope the code will help you achieve what you want

Comment: **this only retrieve first record. UPDATE Please look at it.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of which record you are on and increment it by one.

```
int record_position = -1;

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.Button01:
        // Get all contacts
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
        if (record_position == -1){
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                record_position = c.getPosition();
                DisplayContact(c);
            }
        }
        else if (c.moveToPosition(record_position+1))            
            record_position = c.getPosition();
            DisplayContact(c);
        }
        else {
            if(c.moveToFirst){
                record_position = c.getPosition();
                DisplayContact(c);
            }
        }
        db.close();
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: this only retrieve first record. UPDATE Please look at it.

Comment: @ehah I saw your other post and I bet I know why it is not working... Notice how I put the variable outside of the onClick. it is important otherwise every time you click you set it back to null.

Comment: Helps when I know what error you are receiving, but try setting the record_position to -1 instead of null. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert your Cursor into a global variable and initialize it where it's appropriate:

```
c = db.getAllContacts();
```

Then on your onClick do the following:

```
 ...
if (c.moveToNextt()) {
    DisplayContact(c);
}
...
```